# Java - numbers with at least one 7 and one 9 in its digit

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to code a program to determine how many positive integers under 1,000,000 have at least one 7 and at least one 9 among its digits by examining the digits in each number from 1 to 999,999 ("brute-force" method). The answer is supposed to be 199,262. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? What is the concrete problem? Split the problems in parts (i.e. methods): 1. loop through numbers and increment a counter if the number fits the requirements. 2. check if a number fits the requirements by splitting it into digits. 3. Check if a digit is 7 or 9.

Comment: I extracted the digits from the integers. My problem is... for example, if the number is 77, since I extracted the digits individually, it counts as 2. Thus, I ended up with a number larger than 199,262.

Comment: The post what you tried, and explain that specific problem you have in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @irispapyrus_ Does you code have to examine the individual digits or can you rely on standard library methods to do it?

Comment: Hint: at some point you need something like `if (numberContains(number, 7) && numberContains(number, 9)) { count++; }`

Comment: @xenteros *199262 isn't the correct answer.* - Care to explain why?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I got suggested by the fact that **the question in the title was originaly different from the one in the body** :( I corrected my code and now I agree

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the number to a String and text if it contains 7 **and** 9

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {

        String text = String.valueOf(i);
        // contains both
        if (text.contains("7") && text.contains("9")) count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: `among its digits by examining the digits in each number` - you're examining characters in each concatenated String.

Comment: @xenteros I asked for confirmation of this in the top-level comments - no reply, so I am assuming that using a standard java class method to do this is OK ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some combinatorics for you:

Number of two digit numbers without a 7 (or without a 9):

```
8*(9^1) = 72
```

Number of 2-digit numbers without a 9 or 7:

```
7*(8^1) = 56
```

Number of 2-digit numbers:

```
9*(10^1) = 90
```

Number of 2-digit numbers with at least one 7 and one 9:

```
90 - 2*72 + 56 = 2
```

Formula for n-digit calculation:

```
= 9*(10^(d-1)) - 2*8*(9^(d-1)) + 7*(8^(d-1))


  9*(10^1+10^2+10^3+10^4+10^5) 

- 2*8*(9^1+9^2+9^3+9^4+9^5)

+ 7*(8^1+8^2+8^3+8^4+8^5) 

= 199262
```

Answer (score -1):

The brute force algorithm:

```
public int count() {
    int count = 0;
    boolean per7 = false;
    boolean per9 = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        int j = i;
        while ((!(per7 && per9)) && j > 1) {
            if (j%10 == 7) {
                per7 = true;
            } if (j%10 == 9) {
                per9 = true;
            }
            j = j/10;
        }
        if (per7 && per9) {
            count++;
        }
        per7 = false;
        per9 = false;
    }
    return count;
}
```

On the other hand, I would suggest using basic knowledge about combinatorics, but I understand that during studies, we often do stupid tasks to learn certain skill.

Comment: Not only you give a solution without explaining it, or even better, without helping the OP find it by himself, but this solution is wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet the question from the title was different than this in the body