# Find all positive integers with at least one 7 and 9 under 1,000,000 but how to fix duplicates?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, duplicates

So, for class I have to code a program that determines how many positive integers are
1) Under 1,000,000
2) Have at least one 7 and a 9 in the number
3) Has to be done with the brute-force method.

While the answer is supposed to be 199,262, I keep getting 228530 due to duplicates, can someone take a look to see where I went wrong here? Thanks!

Similar problem but not the same: [Java - numbers with at least one 7 and one 9 in its digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034038/java-numbers-with-at-least-one-7-and-one-9-in-its-digit)

```
boolean sevNine = false; // a combination of seven and nine in a number
boolean oneNine;
boolean oneSeven;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<1000000; i++) //Runs numbers 1-1000000
{
    oneSeven = false;
    oneNine = false;
    String number2 = " " + (i); //sets a nmber to a string
    int length = number2.length()  -1; //length goes up to the last character 0-j
    for (int j= 0; j <= length; j++) //looking for the first 7 or 9 in string 
    {
        char a = number2.charAt(j); //sets char to the next "letter"
        if (a == '7' && oneSeven != true) //if the number is a 7 and there isnt already a seven
        {
            oneSeven = true; //now there is a seven, 
            for (int k = j+1; k <= length; k++) //checks from the next char up to the length for a 9
            {
                char b = number2.charAt(k);
                if (b == '9') 
                {
                     sevNine = true;
                }
            }           
        }
        else if (a == '9' && oneNine != true)
        {
            oneNine = true;
            for (int l = j+1; l <= length; l++)
            {
                char b = number2.charAt(l);
                if (b == '7')
                {
                    sevNine = true;
                }
            }     
        }
        if (sevNine == true)
        {
            counter++;
            sevNine = false;
            System.out.println(number2);

        }

    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: try using a debugger to analyze the behaviour of your code? The code could be simplified and incorporate the use of breaks to make the code more manageable. As this seems to be an assignment, it will be a good practice for you.

Comment: I get a very different answer, but isn't it just `System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, 1000 * 1000).filter(i -> String.valueOf(i).contains("7") || String.valueOf(i).contains("9")).count());`

Comment: One mistake you have made is to declare the 3 boolean variables at the top level.  You can simplify by declare / initializing them inside the outer loop.

Comment: To add to @Samuel Kok, you can add smart logging in your loops and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Michal this is a better fit for SO than CR because the code isn't working.

Comment: In fact, it should be a "close on sight" in CR.  @Michal please don't recommend another SE site unless you have read and understood the site's scope AND "on topic" criteria.

Comment: What happens when you try `797979`, and why? Anyway, your algorithm is more complicated and fiddly than it needs to be; you should only have a single loop and just set a flag when you encounter any `7` or `9`. Finally, `String.valueOf(i)` is much better than what you have, which also causes a bug, by the way.

Comment: Your wrote "Have at least one 7 ***or*** 9 in the digits", but 199,262 is the result for the case when you have at least once 7 ***and*** at least one 9 in the digits. You have probably misread the assignment.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I was incorrect in my typing. I updated the problem to reflect that. I am looking for both a 7 and 9 in each number

Comment: @firesoup One line brute force answer: `System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, 1000 * 1000).filter(i -> String.valueOf(i).contains("7") && String.valueOf(i).contains("9")).count());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not breaking out of the loop once the `sevNine` is set to true and you increment the counter, so it keeps iterating over each digit on the same number even if it has already included the number... Just add a break statement to exit the for loop iterating over each digit once you increment the counter...

Here's the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean sevNine = false; // a combination of seven and nine in a number
    boolean oneNine;
    boolean oneSeven;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) // Runs numbers 1-1000000
    {
        oneSeven = false;
        oneNine = false;
        String number2 = " " + (i); // sets a nmber to a string
        int length = number2.length() - 1; // length goes up to the last character 0-j
        for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++) // looking for the first 7 or 9 in string
        {
            char a = number2.charAt(j); // sets char to the next "letter"
            if (a == '7' && oneSeven != true) // if the number is a 7 and there isnt already a seven
            {
                oneSeven = true; // now there is a seven,
                for (int k = j + 1; k <= length; k++) // checks from the next char up to the length for a 9
                {
                    char b = number2.charAt(k);
                    if (b == '9') {
                        sevNine = true;
                    }
                }
            } else if (a == '9' && oneNine != true) {
                oneNine = true;
                for (int l = j + 1; l <= length; l++) {
                    char b = number2.charAt(l);
                    if (b == '7') {
                        sevNine = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (sevNine == true) {
                counter++;
                sevNine = false;
                System.out.println(number2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

If you run with the break statement, you should get `199262` as the resulting number.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final long count = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10_00_000)
            .filter(i -> String.valueOf(i).contains("7") && String.valueOf(i).contains("9"))
            .count();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```